# cockpit.jsのspawn()にてパイプを使いたい

Tags: javascript, linux

現在、Cockpitのパッケージを作っているのですが、spawn()にてパイプを使うことはできないのでしょうか？
開発環境はCentOS 8です。

該当のコード

```js
cockpit.spawn(['/usr/bin/cat', '/etc/httpd/conf/sites-available/example.conf', '|', '/usr/local/bin/panalysis', '-c'])
```

(panalysisというのはapache configファイルをjsonに変換するものです。)

これは、`/usr/bin/cat exited with code 1`と返されてしまいました。
恐らくspawnにてパイプを使用できないのかなと思ったのですが、どうすれば良いかわかりません。一応、[これがドキュメント](https://cockpit-project.org/guide/latest/cockpit-spawn)です。

Comment: `|`(パイプ)はシェルの機能ですので、例えば `cockpit.spawn(['/bin/sh', '-c', '/usr/bin/cat /etc/httpd/conf/sites-available/example.conf | /usr/local/bin/panalysis -c']);` などとする必要があります。もしくは `cockpit.script()` を使って、`cockpit.script('/usr/bin/cat /etc/httpd/conf/sites-available/example.conf | /usr/local/bin/panalysis -c');` とします。

Comment: なるほど、そのようにすればいいのですね。cockpit.script()を使おうと思います。ありがとうございます！